# Twitter Bootstrap Rails button dropdown no responding to AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Rails 4 app that is using Bootstrap. I am creating a dashboard page that shows buttons that are color coded to represent the status of the tool it represents. The HTML in the page looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
   <a class="btn custombutton dropdown-toggle btn-success" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="btn0" >
      706-Hydraulic Ram<br> 98061841
   </a>

   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a data-method="post" data-remote="true" href="/update_in_service?id=32" id="in_service" rel="nofollow">In Service</a></li>
       <li><a data-method="post" data-remote="true" href="/update_out_service?id=32" id="out_service" rel="nofollow">Out of Service</a></li>
       <li><a href="/tools/32">view Details</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The two methods linked to look like this:

```
def in_service
 @tool.update(:in_service => true)
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to(root_path) }
   format.js
   end
end


def out_service
  @tool.update(:in_service => false)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(root_path) }
    format.js
  end
end
```

Since there is nothing after the "format.js" Rails should automatically execute a file that has the same name as the method followed by .js.erb. so I have a in_service.js.erb and an out_service.js.erb file. They look like this:

```
$('.in_service').bind('ajax:success', function() {
    $(this).closest('.btn').addClass('.btn-success').removeClass('.btn-warning');
});


$('.out_service').bind('ajax:success', function() {
    $(this).closest('.btn').addClass('.btn-warning').removeClass('.btn-success');
});
```

I don't get any errors on the JS console in the browser when I click on the drop down links. The controller part is working perfect. If I reload the page it will show the button with the modified color. The rails server log shows this:

```
SQL (8.3ms)  UPDATE "tools" SET "in_service" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "tools"."id" = 32  [["in_service", false], ["updated_at", Wed, 28 Aug 2013 22:28:11 PDT -07:00]]
   (1092.8ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered tools/out_service.js.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1383ms (Views: 259.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1104.3ms)
```

So it's actually "rendering" the JS file but the page never changes. I've tried many different jquery selectors to see if it was a problem with that, but came up with the same results. My application.js file has these includes:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require server-time
//= require jquery-table
//= require_tree .
```

I've searched just about everything I can think of and am still stumped. I am terrible at JS and my understanding of it is pretty rudimentary. Thanks.

Edit ----

So I made the changes suggested by HAWK but something about it doesn't work with my setup. I get this in the Chrome JS console:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/update_in_service?btn_id=btn0&id=29&in_service=false 500    (Internal Server Error)                          jquery.js?body=1:8725
send                           jquery.js?body=1:8725
jQuery.extend.ajax                           jquery.js?body=1:8155
$.rails.rails.ajax                           jquery_ujs.js?body=1:73
$.rails.rails.handleRemote                           jquery_ujs.js?body=1:149
(anonymous function)                           jquery_ujs.js?body=1:299
jQuery.event.dispatch                           jquery.js?body=1:5117
elemData.handle                           jquery.js?body=1:4788
```

and in the web server log:

```
Completed 400 Bad Request in 10ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing - param not found: tool:
```

It's as if it is no longer getting the :tool parameter which is required as I am on Rails 4 using strong params. The data side of everything was working under my old code, the only thing that wasn't happening was the javascript update of the css style on the element. I rolled my code back to the original and when I click on the drop down menu the web server shows:

```
Started POST "/update_in_service?id=29" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-29 10:28:11 -0700
Processing by ToolsController#in_service as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"29"}
Tool Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "tools".* FROM "tools" WHERE "tools"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "29"]]
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "tools" SET "in_service" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "tools"."id" = 29  [["in_service", true], ["updated_at", Thu, 29 Aug 2013 10:28:11 PDT -07:00]]
(1245.5ms)  COMMIT
Rendered tools/in_service.js.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1266ms (Views: 6.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1249.5ms)
```

I even changed the .js.erb files to target one of the buttons directly by ID to make sure it wasn't a selector problem:

```
$('#btn7').addClass('.btn-success').removeClass('.btn-warning');
```

I saw a link about something in bootstrap or rails stopping the JS from ever being executed in a bootstrap drop down but am still trying to find the link. Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but on first glance I see you're binding to the classes `.in_service` and `.out_service`, while the links only have the ids, `#in_service` and `#out_service`.

Comment: I thought so too and tried both in my code previously without a change in results.

Comment: ARGHH!!! This is driving me mad. I am going to just leave it for now and talk to a Javascript programmer this week. The only thing I was ever able to get to actually work in the ...js.erb files was: `$(document).click();` which would actually close the dropdown menu since it simulates clicking away from the dropdown. But if I try to do ANYTHING else in that .js.erb file it doesn't work. Any suggestions on how to fire the addClass/removeClass from the click event?

Comment: I even tried just putting a `alert( "Handler for .click() called." );` inside the click as a function call and it kills it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured this one out. The key was having the workflow down: `:remote => true` connects to the `toggle_in_service` method in the controller that then calls the `toggle_in_service.js.erb` file which finally calls `toggle_button.html.erb`. I also found that when working in Bootstrap it's probably best to try and target an existing `<div>` for replacement rather than wrap a piece of bootstrap code in another div. Not sure on that but it seemed to matter. Here is the code that worked:

dashboard.html.erb view snippet:

```
 <% status_link = tool.in_service ? "Put Out of Service" : "Put In Service" %>
 <% button_link = "#{tool.location}-#{tool.name.singularize}"+'<br>'+" #{tool.serial}" %>
 <div class="btn-group" id="btn<%= tool.id %>" >

    <a class="btn custombutton dropdown-toggle <%= (tool.in_service  ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-warning') %>" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"  >
      <%=  raw(button_link) %>
    </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><%= link_to status_link, toggle_in_service_path(:id => tool.id), :method => :post, :remote => true %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "view Details", tool_path(tool.id) %></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

This creates a Bootstrap dropdown menu attached to a button that is color coded by the status of the tool.

The first link in the dropdown menu is a remote ajax call to the `toggle_in_service` controller, passing the tool.id paramter. The controller method looks like:

```
def toggle_in_service
   status_change = @tool.in_service ? false : true
   @tool.update(:in_service => status_change)
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to(@tool) }
     format.js
  end
end
```

The boolean value for tool.in_service gets flipped and then calls `toggle_in_service.js.erb`:

```
<% btn_id = "btn#{@tool.id}" %>

$('#<%=btn_id%>').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "toggle_button") %>');
```

Which does an AJAX render of the `_toggle_button.html.erb` partial:

```
<% button_link = "#{@tool.location}-#{@tool.name.singularize}"+'<br>'+" #{@tool.serial}" %>
<% status_link = @tool.in_service ? "Put Out of Service" : "Put In Service" %>

<a class="btn custombutton dropdown-toggle <%= (@tool.in_service  ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-warning') %>" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"  >
  <%=  raw(button_link) %>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><%= link_to status_link, toggle_in_service_path(:id => @tool.id), :method => :post, :remote => true %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "view Details", tool_path(@tool.id) %></li>
</ul>
```

Works great! The entire `div` for the dropdown and the button get updated by AJAX. I'm posting this in case someone looks for something similar. I search many hours on the web and on Stack Overflow, but never found what I needed. I did some reading up on Rails AJAX to figure out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is not answer, but I will give my suggestions. First of all you don't need two actions making same things. Try this

**Controller**

```
def in_service
 @tool.update(:in_service => params[:in_service])
 @success = params[:in_service]
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to(root_path) }
   format.js
   end
end
```

In view add parameters to query

**View**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a data-method="post" data-remote="true" href="/update_in_service?id=32&in_service=true" id="in_service" rel="nofollow">In Service</a></li>
    <li><a data-method="post" data-remote="true" href="/update_in_service?id=32&in_service=false" id="out_service" rel="nofollow">Out of Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="/tools/32">view Details</a></li>
</ul>
```

Don't need to listen ajax bindings

**js.erb**

```
<% if @success %>
  $('.btn').addClass('.btn-success').removeClass('.btn-warning');
<% else %>
    $('.btn').addClass('.btn-warning').removeClass('.btn-success');
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking it needed DRYing up but so still so stumped by the other problem. I will try your code to test the binding issue. I got my binding code from another how-to so I didn't know if it was needed or not. I see what you are doing though, and it makes sense. More sense than most javascript does to me, LOL.

Comment: I edited my post above. Tried what you suggested but kept getting errors with the webserver. My code does work, but there's something that is stopping the JS from changing the page. Could it be turbo links?

Comment: There is error in your code `ActionController::ParameterMissing - param not found: tool:` Change it to `params` instead of `param`. Try again, then let me know if it will fix your problem.

Comment: Actually no, that's not an error. I went back and checked the code, it is correct as far as parameters. I am using Rails 4 so I have all my parameters wrapped in: `def tool_params
      params.require(:tool).permit(:name, :serial, etc...
    end`

Comment: Something in your code drops the @tool variable when passing to the controller. I messed around for an hour or trying to find out why then just reverted to my code since the server data side of my code is working. This is purely a matter of the way Bootstrap interferes with AJAX in menu drop downs. I am going to try [jquery-dropdown](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/) instead.