# Rails like button not updating with Ajax (make_flaggable gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using the make_flaggable gem to create a "like" button called `:fav`. I've got code working, but I can't seem to transition it to Ajax so it updates dynamically. The problem might be in my `link_to` action or the `redirect_to`, but I don't know what to change it to. Any help is appreciated!

**events_controller.rb**

```
def fav
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  current_user.toggle_flag(@event, :fav) #toggles the fav

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
  end
end
```

**helpers/events_helper.rb**

```
def toggle_fav(event, user)
  link_to
    user.flagged?(event, :fav) ? #if the user has already flagged(favoured) the event
    content_tag(:span, " ", :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-heart") : #show a full heart icon
    content_tag(:span, " ", :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"), #show an empty heart icon
    fav_event_path(event), #this updates the database and I think is the cause of the problem
    :remote => true
end
```

**views/events/fav.js.erb**

```
$('.fav-heart').html("<%= escape_javascript toggle_fav(event, current_user) %>");
```

**views/events/index.html.erb** (what pertains to the fav)

```
<li class="fav-heart">
  <%= toggle_fav(event, current_user) %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see it looks like your link_to code might be at fault? Is the ? operation being spread across 3 lines like that or did you just shorten it for viewability here on SO?

This should be valid:

```
link_to user.flagged?(event, :fav) ? content_tag(:span, " ", :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-heart") : content_tag(:span, " ", :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"), fav_event_path(event), :remote => true
```

But if you are breaking up a ? operation across multiple line I don't think it will work. It's bad form anyway, multi-line if/then should use an if statement for readability.

Comment: Also on the one line ? version you might wrap the ? statement in parens for readability, not sure if the link_to method is getting confused or not.

Comment: I've split it here for readability, but it's one line in my actual helper. Changed it to a multi-line if statement, but the outcome wasn't any different.

Comment: :-/ hmmm... I'm in a similar boat as you. I filed [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503168/twitter-bootstrap-rails-button-dropdown-no-responding-to-ajax) trying to get a javascript response to update the class on a button element. Everything is working perfect server side but nothing happens in the browser. Can you post the logs from your web server when you click the button?