# How user collection select in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

in my app i want show to user some Posts, but posts have city, what i need to do, to show posts from selected city, user select some city and in view displays all posts of selected city?
file Post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    NORMAL    = 1
  ACTIVE    = 2
  COMPLETED = 3

    STATUSES = {
    NORMAL    => 'unpublished',
    ACTIVE    => 'published',
    COMPLETED => 'deleted'
  }

  def status_name
    STATUSES[status]
  end

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :city


  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }

end
```

file Posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def index
       @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @feed_items = @category.posts.where(status: params[:status], city_id: params[:city_id]).paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
end
```

file posts/index.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'all posts') %>

<div class="container">
<div class="row post_feed">
    <h1><%= @category.name %></h1>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="padding:0;">
        <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item"><%= link_to 'all categories', all_post_path %> </li>
<% Category.all.each do |category| %>
<li class="list-group-item"><%= link_to category.name, category_posts_path(category) %> 
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="all_post_feed">
                <ul>
                    <div class= "city_select">
                    <%= collection_select(:post, :city_ids, City.all, :id, :name) %>
                    </div>
<%= render 'categories/feed' %>
</ul>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

file categories/_feed.html.erb

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>

    <%= render partial: 'categories/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>

  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
  <% else %>
<% end %>

file categories/_feed_item.html.erb

<li>
    <div class="row post_name" >
        <div class="col-md-8 ">
            <h3>
<%= link_to (truncate feed_item.name,:length => 35),    feed_item %>
</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 preview-small">
            <div class="feed_price pull-right">
<% if feed_item.price.to_f == 0 %>
                price
                <% else %>
                <%= number_to_currency feed_item.price %>
            <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row post_user">
        <div class="col-md-5"> 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 user_avatar">
            <%= avatar_for feed_item.user, :size => "50x50" %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
<%= link_to feed_item.user.name,    (feed_item.user) %><br>
<% if feed_item.user.reviews.count.to_f == 0 %>

                        <% else %>
                    <%= (feed_item.user.reviews.count) %>
                    <% end %>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 adress">
            <span class="pull-right">
                <%= feed_item.status_name %>
                    <%= l feed_item.date, format: :long %> г.</span><br><span class="pull-right">
                    <%= (truncate feed_item.adress1,:length => 90) %></span><br>
    <span class="pull-right">published <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> назад.

    </span>

        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

when user select city rails show him all posts from selected city

```
<%= collection_select(:post, :city_ids, City.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Comment: what is your current outcome? Are you having a specific problem? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: thanks, now all works, but rails show all posts, from all cities, i want to show for user posts from selected city, user select city and rails show him posts from selected city)

Comment: So you want the city select drop down to cause the page to show just posts from that city? You probably need some sort of `submit` or AJAX call to make the feed show just the posts for the city selected. Right now it looks like you render a page with a drop down menu and a feed, but no way to submit the city, or javascript to update the `div` for the feeds.

Comment: could you give an example with submit? please

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that good that I can just write one up quickly. I know what you want to do, but it would take me a few hours at least to write up an example, even with all your code. You can see an example of how I wrote a drop down menu that does an Ajax call here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503168/twitter-bootstrap-rails-button-dropdown-no-responding-to-ajax just scroll down to the accepted answer to see the workflow. I just don't have enough free time to commit right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this

```
<%= form_for :posts, url: category_posts_path, :html => { :method => 'GET' } do |f| %>
        <%= select_tag :city_id, options_from_collection_for_select(City.all, :id, :name, params[:city_id]), include_blank: true %>
            <% end %>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#city_id').change(function(){
        $('form').submit();
      });
        $('#status').change(function(){
        $('form').submit();
         });
    });
    </script>
```